# read and output pdf file as file format

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am new in pdfbox.

my manager gives a pdf file and told me to read this file by any of the technologies(python, java).

issues are we have a pdf file we need to read the same and write as what we read.
means
sample.pdf
[image: sample pdf format]

need to write output as shown in the image.

Had gone through PDFTextStripper but not sure about how to use.

worked on java pdf file creation, but not able to read and write like the same format that read.

please suggest how to attain the same.

Comment: Re PDFTextStripper, please show what you tried. There are enough examples on the pdfbox website and here. The rest of your question is very unclear. What is "read", what is "write"? "Reading" a file could be as little as opening it with NOTEPAD++. "Writing" a file could be as little as doing `copy source.pdf destination.pdf`. And why are you asking about writing, but you also wrote that "my manager gives a pdf file and told me to read this file". He didn't told you to "write", so what is it?

Comment: Do you by *"need to write output as shown in the image."* mean that you need to write the output as a bitmap image? Or as plain text? Or text with data like coordinates, fonts, transformation, ...? Please clarify. (And if you don't know the answer, please ask your manager to clarify what he wants.)

Comment: need to extract text from pdf as we humans read, read first paragraph.
then second paragragh
please help me i was using pdfbox in java
is it possible with pyton
checked to read as html, but it came as div for each letter,
is there any solution.

Comment: hi 
issue was i used 
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
now its working as per needed,
but comes another issue, the intent is not matching as per orginal pdf.
How to keep the intent as in orginal pdf file.
output is in java output(netbeans)

Comment: I assume you mean the indent, i.e. the horizontal position. PDFBox does not insert blanks to simulate indents. You would have to painfully implement this yourself by looking at the positions of the individual characters. See PrintTextLocations.java in the source code download to get an idea about positions.